# How to avoid dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It's cool to fight dragons and all but sometimes I just want to wander around and find some new places and BOOM a dragon comes from nowhere and start to follow my trails and wants to burn my arse.

How can I tell him to get lost and don't get into a fight?

Comment: Sneak.  Sometimes they will leave if they can't find you.  I'm not sure how consistently this works.

Comment: Not sure if this always works, but I've gone into a nearby building for a little while and when I came back out the dragon wasn't around, and I had enough time to fast travel elsewhere.

Comment: I've found that sprinting helps. If I can put some distance between me and the dragon he'll usually give up.

Comment: A horse is pretty good, used mine to get away from all kinds of truble!

Comment: One time I was at a village and all I did was use the first shout at it and it flew away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually carry **invisibility potions** with me,use it when you see dragon to get some head start and sprint further he will stop chasing you or you can at least get far away to fast travel,it might be a bad option to fast-travel if you haven't discovered any nearby locations to restore your journey.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Dragonrend as fast as I can on the dragon which causes it to land, so I try to escape by jumping off a few rocks or sneaking behind some cover.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with not doing the main quest line until you discover all the locations you want, you can not kill the dragon at the Whiterun watchtower and no dragons will attack you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running away on a horse or something. Once you master it, (by that I mean running away in the right direction and when) it becomes really easy.