# How can I avoid Elder Dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I keep finding Elder Dragons just outside of Whiterun, but I'm only on level 27, just walking around discovering caves. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the best you can do is keep moving and [hope they do not notice you](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36206/). The dragons along with everything else in the game scale themselves to you and it is deemed at your level that elder dragons should appear. This is a blanket scaling though so if you just spent time raising your crafting and other non combat skills to get most of your levels then you are going to be at a disadvantage for a while in combat.